# How to put different reusable codes in to common feature file

Tags: karate

I have 2 reusable features (Currently saved as different feature File and passing arguments)

**First**

```
@ignore
Feature: Login Application Function

  Background:

  Scenario: Login to the application 
  And input(loginPage.userName, user)
  And input(loginPage.password, password)
  When submit().click(loginPage.signIn)
```

**Second**

```
@ignore
Feature: Search Employee By First and Last Name

  Background:

  Scenario: Search by first Name and Last Name

   And input(SearchEmployee.firstName, firstNameVal)
   And input(SearchEmployee.lastName, firstNameVal)
   When submit().click(SearchEmployee.searchButton)
```

Is there any way to put both these features in a single Common feature file and Call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call

```
* call read('first.feature')
* call read('second.feature')
```